# How to override 'where' in rails 3

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, overriding

I have upgraded my application from rails 2.3.8 to 3.0.3 . But I'm facing a problem. I was using 'find' but the overriding doesn't work in rails 3:

```
# override activerecord's find to allow us to find by name or id transparently
  def self.find(*args)
    if args.is_a?(Array) and args.first.is_a?(String) and (args.first.index(/[a-zA-Z\-_]+/) or args.first.to_i.eql?(0) )
      find_by_login_slug(args)
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to make this work in rails 3 or even by using where instead.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

The problem you're are facing is an upgrading from a rails 2.3.X to a rails 3.0.X application. Although, it could seem a simple task it isn't, especially if you have a real application and not a toy one. I suggest you to take a look to a screencast series from Rayn Bates, you could start from http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1 to get a complete idea off the problem you are facing.

If you only need to read about ActiveRecord new interface http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface is a great article.

Comment: Have you ever heard about overriding? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding . my problem isn't in the upgrading. I already passed it. my problem is when I called User.find('any name'). it calls the overriding method which i made in rails 2. but in rails 3 gives me an error says: "Couldn't find User with ID='any name'". because it isn't seeing the overriding method

Comment: Yes I do know what method overriding is. I was just suggesting it's not a good solution trying to use it here. I can't think about a good case where you have really use method overriding for the find method of activerecord